# Background image with gradient in Scaffold

Tags: flutter

I try to get a default background with gradient, on a scaffold.
The latest attempt i get nearly what i want but is the wrong way. everything is behind the background. I overlook something but not sure what:

```
class MainPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MainPage({super.key});

  @override
  State<MainPage> createState() => _MainPageState();
}

class _MainPageState extends State<MainPage> {
  double value = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    SizeConfig().init(context);

    return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              gradient: LinearGradient(
                begin: Alignment.topCenter,
                end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                colors: [
                  kMainColor.withOpacity(1),
                  kMainColor.withOpacity(0.2)
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
          SafeArea(
            child: Container(
              width: SizeConfig.safeBlockVertical! * 34,
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  DrawerHeader(
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: const [
                        CircleAvatar(
                          backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                          radius: 60,
                          backgroundImage: NetworkImage(
                              'https://www.urltologo/apps/config/logo.png'),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    child: ListView(
                      children: const [
                        DrawerContent(
                          icon: Icons.crisis_alert,
                          titleText: 'Mega',
                        ),
                        DrawerContent(
                          icon: Icons.access_alarm,
                          titleText: 'Programmering',
                        ),
                        DrawerContent(
                          icon: Icons.list,
                          titleText: 'Playlist',
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
          TweenAnimationBuilder(
            tween: Tween<double>(begin: 0, end: value),
            duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
            curve: Curves.ease,
            builder: (_, double val, __) {
              return (Transform(
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                transform: Matrix4.identity()
                  ..setEntry(3, 2, 0.001)
                  ..setEntry(0, 3, 200 * val)
                  ..rotateY((pi / 6) * val),
                child: ClipRRect(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(value == 1 ? 20 : 0),
                  child: Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      border: Border.all(
                          width: value == 1 ? 1 : 0, color: Colors.black54),
                    ),
                    child: Stack(
                      children: [
                        Scaffold(
                          appBar: appBar(),
                          bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar(
                            color: kHighlightColor,
                            child: Row(
                              children: [const Text('1'), const Text('2')],
                            ),
                          ),
                          body: const Text('Swipe naar rechts'),
                        ),
                        Container(
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            gradient: LinearGradient(
                              begin: Alignment.topCenter,
                              end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                              colors: [
                                kDarkGreen.withOpacity(0.6),
                                kDarkGreen.withOpacity(0.3),
                                kMainColor.withOpacity(0.8),
                                kMainColor.withOpacity(0.8)
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                          child: Container(
                            color: Colors.transparent,
                            height: double.infinity,
                            width: double.infinity,
                            child: Image.asset(
                              'lib/assets/images/background.png',
                              fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ));
            },
          ),
          GestureDetector(
            onHorizontalDragStart: (details) => setState(
              () {
                value == 0 ? value = 1 : value = 0;
              },
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  appBar() {
    return AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        elevation: 1,
        toolbarHeight: SizeConfig.blockSizeVertical! * 20);
  }
}
```

There are two screens: a hidden menu with the listview, and the mainpage over the menu page. So the menu screen is not visible till you swipe it. If i put the code in the mainpage as above in the second scaffold, then all content i add has the gradient over it, and has not the right color.

Anyone an idea what i am doing wrong here ? I tried to change order of the stack also but then the complete color thingie is gone again.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can remove provides and other data to make it minimal while  the question is focused on UI.

Comment: Removed some code:)

Comment: What is behind the background I still do not understand. I ran your code, removed some unnecessary things but still no idea what you need here.

Comment: i got a perfect gradient with the widget infront of the gradient

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i tried to remove and change unnecessary part of code, and change it into this

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        title: 'Flutter Demo',
        theme: ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        ),
        home: Scaffold(
          extendBodyBehindAppBar: true,
          appBar: AppBar(
            backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
            elevation: 0,
          ),
          body: Stack(
            children: [
              Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  gradient: LinearGradient(
                    begin: Alignment.topCenter,
                    end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                    colors: [
                      Colors.red.withOpacity(1),
                      Colors.green.withOpacity(0.2)
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              SafeArea(
                child: Container(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      Column(
                        children: const [
                          Text(
                            "Yea here you are, it work properly",
                            style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 28,
                                color: Colors.white,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```

and as you say that

> everything is behind the background

but when I tried your base code it should got no problem, I think it relate of your `listview` so all the widget you have is gone from the design.
this is the result I got from the code that I create
[image]

Comment: There are two screens: a hidden menu with the listview, and the mainpage over the menu page. So the menu  screen is good is not visible indeed.

If i put the code in the mainpage in the scaffold, then all content i add has the gradient over it, and has not the right color.

The gradient indeed works but not in my code. That is why i had all the code initial

Comment: I fixed it based on your example! I realized i had the Scaffold inside the stack. Turned it around and now it works. Thanks!

Comment: yea only 1 `scaffold` in a only single page. glad it help too